# Guessing starting values for PARAMETERS statement in PROC NLIN

Tags: sas, nonlinear-regression

How to guess what should be the starting values for beta estimates, which we need to specify in PARMS or PARAMETERS statement while using PROC NLIN (PROC NLIN is used to run non-linear regression in SAS)

Comment: Depends on the model, so tell us if you have a specific one in mind rather than wanting to know about general approaches you might take. The user guide for NLINs gives [an example](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_nlin_sect005.htm) for the Michaelis-Menten kinetic model.